# Chrome can't load certain sites but Safari can - how can I diagnose the problem?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

**Please note:** this question is from 2013, but it's received some recent answers (2017). I personally haven't experienced this problem for several years. It's possible that others still have the same issue and that answers to this question might help them -- but it seems more likely that my problem was fixed long ago and that more recent issues are actually a different problem.

---

When accessing the internet from my home connection, Google Chrome has trouble accessing certain sites that use https. These include Google search, Facebook and discussions.apple.com, but for some reason Gmail is ok. This is on a Retina Macbook Pro with 10.8.3 Mountain Lion.

Given the symptoms described below, it the issue seems likely to be some misconfiguration of the router, which unfortunately I'm not in a position to change. However, since it works in Safari but not Chrome, the two browsers must be doing something differently. What I would really like to know is how I can diagnose what this difference is.

What happens when I try to access the site varies depending on the site. Google search works intermittently, and when it doesn't work it times out as if the server was down. Facebook.com consistently renders the first two wall posts but then stops loading. The Apple forums just sit there forever with a white screen.

I can access these sites just fine in Safari, and they also work fine when I'm browsing via the WiFi at work. It's only when I'm (a) using the ethernet cable at home, *and* (b) using Google Chrome that the problem occurs. Unfortunately I have no access to the router at home, because the internet is part of my rental agreement and I just have an ethernet socket in my room.

I have tried the following things (and possibly more) to no avail:

- Clearing all brower data in Chrome (cache, cookies etc.)
- Disabling all extensions and restarting Chrome
- Switching to Google public DNS
- Checking my proxy settings in OS X. (No proxies are configured. Both Safari and Chrome use the system settings.)
- Checking that my IP address is the same when browsing via https from Chrome and Safari (it is.)
- Looking for any suspicious messages in Console. (There are several about things relating to Spotlight, but nothing relating to Chrome, and nothing comes up when I try to load these sites.)
- Disabling "Predict network actions to improve page load performance" in Chrome preferences. This changes the symptoms slightly (Facebook times out instead of displaying the first two wall posts; other sites behave the same as before) but does not resolve the issue.
- Rebooting into safe mode
- Deleting my Chrome profile
- Deleting all the other files in ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome
- Setting ipv6 to "Link-local only" in system preferences
- Turning off ipv6 completely by running `networksetup -setv6off Ethernet` in Terminal
- Accessing the web via TOR. The problem does not occur, but the connection is too slow for regular use.

My question is, what else can I do to try and work out what the problem is? Chrome is obviously doing something different from what Safari does when trying to access these sites, and I'd like to know what that is, with a view to either solving the problem for myself, or at least being able to submit a bug report to whichever party is responsible.

Comment: What Chrome version do yo have?

Comment: @Buscar웃 version 26.0.1410.65. It is the latest version according to "About Google Chrome".

Answer (score 4):

You did eventing right except for one step.

Making new account.

Quit Google Chrome completely.

Go to the Go menu > Go to Folder.

Enter the following directories in the text field, then press Go.
    ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/

Locate the folder called "**Default**" in the directory window that opens and rename it as "Backup default."

Try opening Google Chrome again. A new "Default" folder is automatically created as you start using the browser.

Alternatively you can "teach" your browser.

That is done by adding the :80 to the web address.

Example www.myseite.com:80

Also run the netstat -a -p tcp  to see if https (443) are open)

Last not least, turn off the experimental "Built-in Asynchronous DNS" is Disabled in chrome://flags/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I already tried this. (It's what I meant by "deleting my Chrome profile".) Even after doing this the problem still persisted.

Comment: You mentioned from "Home", does it work on another network ?

Comment: there might be an issue with how your system handles the sites certificates.  Try adding :80 http://www.(any site).com:80
if that doesn't work try 443 for secure http
https://www.(any site).com:443

Comment: Yeah, it works OK on the wireless at work, just not using my home connection. Where exactly should I add these lines that you mention? (In Keychain Access somewhere? Or somewhere in Chrome?)

Comment: add at the end, after the (.com) like www.mywebsite.com:80

Comment: It sounds like it is your home router !

Comment: Oh I see what you mean now. I tried going to facebook.com:80 and it worked, but it seems the whole problem has fixed itself for the moment. I'll try it again if it comes back. (This is weird, since it's been happening for a week ever since I moved in. Unless there's a chance that just doing that could have fixed it?)

Comment: It could well be a problem with the router - as I said, I unfortunately don't have access to the router, since my internet is provided directly via an ethernet socket in my room. But if the problem is with the router, it seems weird that it would affect only Chrome and not Safari.

Comment: OK, so it worked, now your Chrome browser will remember that and it should work from now on.

Comment: If it works and you are satisfied with the answer please use the check mark to close it.

Comment: I'll accept the answer if you edit it so that it describes the :80 trick, which is apparently what solved the problem. Or I can do the edit if you prefer. But if you're able to explain why it worked I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: adding :80 just means you're explicitly going to port 80 and are no longer accessing the site via https.  IMO this is not a great solution to your actual problem.

Comment: The problem is back now - it must have been a coincidence that it temporarily fixed itself last night. (This is what I suspected.)

Comment: @Nathaniel I would contact the sys admin of your supplier - you mentioned a dorm room so this might be a specialist not a general ISP

Answer (score 2):

Hi I was having the same issue on MacOS Sierra and the issue was resolved by opening a new incognito window and then it works.
After which I resume to the normal chrome mode and all websites load successfully.

Hope this helps anyone.

TC

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the incognito mode? <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> and trying the websites again from that page?

Comment: I guess it can't hurt to try. This problem hasn't happened for a while, but if it happens again I'll give that a go.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug with Chrome and XP.  There appears to be no resolution.

Answer (score 0):

If you have downloaded the Google Chrome Ad Block extension, try customizing it by clicking on “Show ads on a webpage or domain”, then typing the problematic webpage address into the “The domain or url where AdBlock shouldn’t block anything field”, then hitting the “OK!” button.

Answer (score 0):

The Incognito mode worked for me. But it didn't hold up back in normal mode.
Had to go to *Settings* / *Advanced settings* / *Privacy* and click the *Content settings…* button, then go to *Cookies* and click the *All cookies and site data…* button; then search for `problemsite.com` and hit the *Remove all* button.

This worked for me (on Windows 10).

Answer (score 0):

I have been using VPN service in China.And I got same problem here and found out I just had to disable one extension called "unlock youku" which prevented all the ads in a local video webisite in Chrome. Then the chrome is compatible with VPN service.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all of the steps above and none of them worked. The solution for me was rebooting the Modem/Router.

It made no sense to me because I was able to access the site on Safari but not on Chrome. Simple Modem/Router Reset did the trick.